# Self referencing struct-like object with numba in python

Tags: python, c++, struct, numba

For multiple reasons, I have to translate C++ code to python and still make it as fast as possible. After trying multiple options like concurrent.futures, its still a  bit too slow for my liking but i've been trying to use Numba to make it faster. There's a small part of the C++ code thats giving me trouble and it's a self-referencing structure:

```
struct node_struct{

  int neighbourindex;
  struct node_struct *next;
};

typedef struct node_struct node;
```

I need to fill a numpy array of these structures and fill them over time in loops and i cant seem to make it work.

Does anyone have encounterd this before or has any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own machinery for a linked list, you can rebuild your code around [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque), typically used when you need to implement linked lists, queues, stacks, round-robins...

It's hard to write Python code to beat an available library implementation in terms of speed.